# Determine to show or not show excel drop down dependently

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, show

I have 2 columns. Column A will item, Column B will show drop down. Items other then "FOC" item will show 4 drop down options "$1, $2, $3, $4" in Column B, but FOC item will not show any drop down.

[image]

Can anyone show how to show or not show options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I looked on this site for [excel dependent dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5Ddependent+dropdown) and found 48 answers immediately. Which of these are not working for you? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937034/how-to-dynamically-change-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-for-dropdown-in-excel/31938344?s=4|1.9993#31938344) isn't on that list but should help you.

Comment: Hi, I know how to use data validation to return list. How about do not show dropdown arrow, instead of showing arrow but no drop down option?

Comment: That would require VBA to remove the Data validation, List when column A changes and put it back when columns A changes again. A DV list can be empty but to remove it completely requires VBA.